# on click function not working if html written inside php

Tags: php, jquery, html

see my code here

```
if(isset($_POST['table_category_view'])){
        $result = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT id,category FROM '.$ps_category_table_name,ARRAY_A);
        $html = "";
        foreach ($result as $value){
            $id = $value['id'];
            $categry = $value['category'];
            $html .= '<tr id="catgry-row' . $id . '">';
            $html .= '<td id="catgry-row' . $id . '">'.$categry.'</td>';
            $html .= '<td><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="edit-catgry' . $id . '" onclick="edit_category("' . $id . '");">Edit</button>';
            $html .= '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="delete-catgry' . $id . '" onclick="delete_category("' . $id . '");">Delete</button>';
            $html .= '<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="display:none" id="update-catgry' . $id . '" onclick="update_category("' . $id . '");">Update</button>';
            $html .= '<button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" style="display:none" id="cancel-update-catgry' . $id . '" onclick="cancel_update_category("' . $id . '");">Cancel</button></td></tr>';
        }
        echo $html;
    }
```

here how to write onclick function in my code it was not working please give me solution

Comment: It's all about the way you do the concatenation, it should be: `$html .= '<td><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="edit-catgry' . $id . '" onclick="edit_category('. (int)$id.');">Edit</button>';`

Comment: you should Escape Sequence.
`$html = '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="delete-catgry' . $id . '" onclick="delete_category(\'' . $id . '\');">Delete</button>'`

Comment: For info : http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: As an aside, your `<tr>` and `<td>` have the same *id* - I'm guessing the td should be something like: `<td id="category-cell...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

enclose your sentence inside the `double quote ("")` not single code & write your code as below,

```
$html = "<td><button class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' id='edit-catgry".$id." ' onclick=edit_category('$id');>Edit</button>";
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to write the function parameter like this in php.

```
 onclick="edit_category('.$id.');"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:

```html
<?php
if(isset($_POST['table_category_view'])){
 $result = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT id,category FROM '.$ps_category_table_name,ARRAY_A);
 $html = "";
 foreach ($result as $value){
  $id = $value['id'];
  $categry = $value['category'];
  $html .= '<tr id="catgry-row' . $id . '">';
  $html .= '<td id="catgry-row' . $id . '">'.$categry.'</td>';
  $html .= '<td><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="edit-catgry' . $id . '" onclick="edit_category(' . $id . ');">Edit</button>';
  $html .= '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="delete-catgry' . $id . '" onclick="delete_category(' . $id . ');">Delete</button>';
  $html .= '<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="display:none" id="update-catgry' . $id . '" onclick="update_category(' . $id . ');">Update</button>';
  $html .= '<button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" style="display:none" id="cancel-update-catgry' . $id . '" onclick="cancel_update_category(' . $id . ');">Cancel</button></td></tr>';
 }
 echo $html;
}
?>
```